# How can I edit httpd.conf, generated by mod_wsgi 4.4.21 ubuntu

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

I have installed mod_wsgi using `pip` into a virtualenv having `python 3.4`, `django 1.8` and `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)`.

I've read most of the docs on mod_wsgi but no where states how and based on what the httpd.conf is generated. I simply want to enable mod_x-sendfile, what I would do by setting XSendFile on under a virtual host in 000-default.conf. 
But in the new way of using mod_wsgi (which is incredibly easier by the way) it is totally opaque, how one can customize the apache virtual host configuration; namely the traditional httpd.conf or 000-default.conf.

So my question being: where should I put the `XSendFile on` while I use the command: `$python manage.py runmodwsgi` to run my server to enable the processing of x-sendfile headers by apache?

Comment: Enabling/disabling apache modules is usually done with [a2enmod and a2dismod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/a2enmod.8.html).

Comment: @Kenney from that perspective it's enabled, but mod_xsendfile needs further configuration as I stated above, "XSendFile on" must be added to the apache config file under <virtual host: *> if available. But in case of using new version of mod_wsgi and the command I mentioned, a httpd.conf is automatically generated and it's not vivid based upon what

Comment: I see. Well, I always manually configure Apache (and by `apt`). I don't know exactly how `manage.py` generates a `httpd.conf` so I can't help you there, but, you may be able to set `XSendFile on` in a `.htaccess` if `AllowOverride` allows it. Otherwise you could just append the line `XSendFile on` to the httpd.conf file (global scope is inherited by `<VirtualHost *>` AFAIK).

Comment: @Kenney Thanks Kenny, So I'm gonna put the line in apache2.conf and see weather its included in the httpd generated file by manage.py.

Comment: @Kenney So I tried that doesn't work that way it seems; I figured there are lots of options that runmodwsgi can be provided with like request time out or max number of concurent clients or so , but any thing regarding mod_xsendfile unfortunately. So the runwsgi command is provided the options of its own and doesn't inherit form the main config file as far as I understood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was very simple thanks to Graham Dumpleton

Firstly, lots of options could be provided simply in this form of command `$python manage.py runmodwsgi --options`. You can replace `options` with `help` to see a list of options.

secondly, if you want any configuration other than those provided by the `runmodwsgi` command, you could create a config file as in: `extra.conf` and have your configurations included in it, having them loaded using the following command:

```
$python manage.py runmodwsgi --include-file extra.cong
```